# Dynamically Change Lookback Period

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to dynamically adjust the lookback period of a pandas dataframe to run regressions on different lengths of stock data. As an easy example take an MA cross.

```
date        Prices  Diff    signal

20150101    8.5     -1.5    FALSE
20150101    11.5    0.3     TRUE 
20150102    14.5    4.5     FALSE
20150103    16.67   3.66    FALSE 
20150104    18      2       FALSE
20150105    18.5    0.5     FALSE 
20150106    18.17   -2.17   TRUE 
20150107    17      -3      FALSE
```

Diff is the difference between 2 moving averages and signal identifies a cross with true/false. Numbers are arbitrary, just examples. There could be 10, 50, 100, etc rows between each signal.

Now I would like to run a regression on the prices for whatever length exists between signals, so at row 6 I would want prices[-4:], and row 8 I would want prices[-1:].

Could anyone help me out with this problem? Looping backwards in each row until I find the latest signal seems inefficient. Should I simply assign an index value to a variable whenever a signal occurs, and use that variable to define the lookback period? I'm still relatively new to Python and not sure how to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have actually solved this problem, but the solution is not very elegant. If anyone has an elegant solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved this problem, but the solution is not very elegant. If anyone has an elegant solution, please let me know.

```
    if diff[-1] > 0 and diff[-2] < 0:
        signal = True
        over_count += 1
        under_count = 0
    elif diff[-1] < 0 and diff[-2] > 0:
        signal = False
        under_count += 1
        over_count = 0
    elif signal:
        over_count += 1
    elif not signal:
        under_count += 1
```